# psycopg2 OperationalError: cursor does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to implement a server side cursor in order to "bypass" Django ORM weakness when it comes to fetch an huge amount of data from the database.
But I don't understand how named cursor are supposed to be defined, since my current code seems not working properly. I define the cursor in this way:

```
id = 'cursor%s' % uuid4().hex
connection = psycopg2.connect('my connection string here')
cursor = connection.cursor(id, cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
```

The cursor seems to work in that it can be iterated and returns expected records as python dictionary, but when I try to close it (`cursor.close()`) I get the exception:

```
psycopg2 OperationalError: cursor *the generated cursor id* does not exist
```

WTF?! So what is the object I'm using to retrieve stuff from the database?
Is psycopg2 using a fallback default (unnamed) cursor since the one I defined is not found in my database (and if so... my big question: it's mandatory to define a cursor at the db level before using psycopg2?) I'm a lot confused, can you help me?

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, one reason this can happen is if you didn't run migrations (i.e. after pulling down a colleague's changes) and something within Django dies as a result, killing the cursor but hiding underneath this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the psycopg2 documentation:

"Named cursors are usually created WITHOUT HOLD, meaning they live only as long as the current transaction. Trying to fetch from a named cursor after a commit() or to create a named cursor when the connection transaction isolation level is set to AUTOCOMMIT will result in an exception."

Which is to say that these cursors do not need to be explicitly closed.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors

Comment: Mmm... I read that sentence before, but honestly I didn't interpret it as you wrote... I'm afraid of memory leaks, and since a close method exists I don't understand why I should not call it. Moreover I call it immediatly as a test and so I'm supposed to be in the same transaction... or am I wrong?

Comment: I have to say that I'm not sure. As a test, try setting the no hold parameter to True and see if it's possible to close the cursor without any exceptions.

Comment: After some hours of tests, debugging and reading I can say that I don't have to close cursors, but I have indeed to remember to close the connection they are using... I created some nice wrapper classes :)

Comment: @daveoncode: I ran into the same problem, now I wonder if closing the connection is really necessary or if just by commiting it the cursor will be properly closed? From Talvalin's answer I would infer the later, but from your comment, the former. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22):

I made a really simple and silly mistake of forgetting to run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` before running `./manage.py test` which caused this error.

(I'm aware this doesn't answer the original question, but since this is the first result from Google I thought I would contribute.  Hopefully that's okay)

Comment: This solved my problem, I had forgotten to make migrations and the `unit tests` of django rest did not show any related error, but the main application did.

Comment: Another silly mistake for me, although I had run `makemigrations` I had managed to incorrectly name the migration file by adding a `.py.py` extension. I realise we don't normally have to name migration files but in my case I need to run the migration on a minikube cluster and then copy across to my local file system.

Answer (score 14):

I had similar problem and found the solution. Just disable server side cursors like described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#disable-server-side-cursors

```
        'default': {
            ...
            'USER': DB_USER,
            'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
            'NAME': DB_NAME,
            'DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS': True,
            ...
        },
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, what is the consequence of this parameter ? I read that the `iterator` function of a Django queryset is impacted. Thanks

Comment: Without this flag (only PostgreSQL and Oracle) when using `query.iterator()` - it will load entire dataset in memory for iteration. With `SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS` set on, it will load data by chunks and this gives you **lower memory usage** on such iterations. How much lower memory usage? It depends on your application and dataset. I found that in most cases disabling server side cursor won't hurt. For example In Django admin where data displayed in pages, it doesn't give any difference on performance.

Answer (score 12):

I've had this problems when playing around with my models and launching the test with Pytest.

What resolved the problem for me was to reset the database of my test unit. I used --create-db like so:

```
pytest backend/test_projects/partners/test_actions.py --create-db
```